# How to set default value in core data array ? How to override the default value ? How to customize category?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I'm trying to make a Storage Expiration Notification APP.

I create a class called **Product**, here are the properties.

```
@NSManaged public var productName: String?
@NSManaged public var quantity: String?
@NSManaged public var category = ["", "Food", "Daily", "Makeup"]
@NSManaged public var chooseCategory: Int16
@NSManaged public var purchaseDate: String?
@NSManaged public var expiredDate: String?
@NSManaged public var productID: String?
```

But there's an Error showed that **@NSManaged property cannot have an initial value**

Hence, I only can move the **Category** array(use picker controller to choose the values) to `ViewContorller.swift`. But I want to create a Customize Category array that users can change the value. For instance, the default category is `["Food", "Daily", "Makeup"]`, users can change the value to `["Drink", "Wine", "Battery"]`. Should I use archiving, or create a new class? I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: For an array you can use json and for default value, you set it in the database model file.

Answer (score 0):

The Core Data way to do this is by overriding `awakeFromInsert`. That function is inherited from `NSManagedObject` and is called once when the object is first inserted into a managed object context. For this case it would look something like

```
func awakeFromInsert() {
    category = ["", "Food", "Daily", "Makeup"]
}
```

It doesn't work in exactly the same way as a Swift initial value but it has the same effect since it happens when you create a new instance.

Comment: But if I want to change the default value, eg. The users want to customize the category from `category = ["", "Food", "Daily", "Makeup"]` to `["Drink", "Wine", "Battery"]` , how to override the default array value??

Comment: A default is a value used if no other value is provided. If you want to use a different value, assign a different value to the property, same as any other variable. This property's value can be changed like every other Swift property.

Answer (score 0):

The error is right, an *@NSManaged property cannot have an initial value*.

A lightweight Swift solution is a JSON string attribute and a computed property for the conversion.

```
@NSManaged public var category : String
```

and

```
var categoryArray : [String] {
    get { (try? JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: Data(category.utf8))) ?? [] }
    set {
        let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        category = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}
```

Set the default value

```
"[\"\",\"Food\",\"Daily\",\"Makeup\"]
```

either in `awakeFromInsert` or in Interface Builder in the model

Comment: An array of strings can be a transformable property value.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes it can, but as I said the JSON conversion is more lightweight and *swiftier*.

Comment: Nevertheless, "A `@NSManaged` property cannot even be an array" is not correct.